# C# HttpSelfHostServer can I regain control of Controller construction?

Tags: c#, web, self-hosting

Due to limitations on the server side I need to build a self hosting web service in .NET...

I'm currently looking at HttpSelfHostServer but I'm **very** un-cool with it's magical construction of the controller, that seems to be, based on name alone and using only the default constructor.

For my tests I need to inject a value into the controller and using an IoC framework for this one usage where vanilla dependancy injection will suffice is over the top.

Is there any way I can do this with HttpSelfHostServer? or are there other, non-deprecated, self-hosting alternatives that give me control over my controller constructor calls.

Comment: Maybe `System.Net.HttpListener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` instance that you need to provide to the `HttpSelfHostServer` constructor inherits the `DependencyResolver` property from the `HttpConfiguration` class. Hence, you can provide a custom dependency resolver as outlined [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver), for instance.

Comment: Sigh, this is what I feared... I have to write a ton of boilerplate code just because I have no control over my own object construction.

Comment: If you use a ready-made DependencyResolver this becomes dead-simple, really. Look [here](http://netmvc.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html) for some instructions on how to use the [Unity.WebAPI package](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI).

Comment: Thanks SG, looks like my only option is to seek an alternative. I'm very concerned HttpSelfHostServer is not allowing me, the developer, to choose the level of complexity of my own project... I just don't want to include an IoC framework to pass a single parameter into a constructor. But thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to override `IHttpControllerActivator` in a unit test, I think it's similar to what you're trying to do.

e.g.

```
httpConfiguration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), 
 Mock<IHttpControllerActivator>());
```

(there's more info. about services [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/configuring-aspnet-web-api))